# stubby4j handling SOAP request

Tags: soap, stubby4j

I like to serve a default response form stubby4j for a SOAP request with the same value I am receiving in request.

```
post: "[\\s\\S]*param1.([^<]+)[\\s\\S]*param2.([0-9]+)[\\s\\S]*param3.([^<]+)[\\s\\S]*param4.([^<]+)[\\s\\S]*"
```

Now the problem is, I can't ensure the sequence of input parameters coming in the request. So there is a chance that param2 comes first.

How can we handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dint need it. I noticed that requests coming from the same client maintains the sequence of input field. So I need not to worry to compare or capture them with different patterns.

However due to some limitations of stubby4j, I have made my own utility and switched to [stubby-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stubby-db) now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Amit Kumar Gupta,

Thank you for using stubby4j and thank you for your question and I am really sorry for replying late. You are welcomed to have a look at stubby4j library now, the docs are at: https://stubby4j.com, as it has undergone many changes and improvements since 2016. I hope you can find features needed, if not, please raise an issue or a feature request.

In addition to `HTTP/1.1`, it also supports behavior stubbing over `HTTP/2` and `WebSockets` (over HTTP/1.1) protocols. In the near future it will support WebSockets bootstrapping over HTTP/2

Plus, stubby4j has been Dockerized with the official images stored at https://hub.docker.com/r/azagniotov/stubby4j

Thank you.